# Visual Studio giving temporary errors referring to class (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm having real trouble with references to a class object in a different file. I have a Main class which does stuff, and another class called MainMap which does different stuff. They look like this:

Main.h

```
#pragma once
#include "D3DGraphics.h"
#include "Filesystem.h"
#include "MainMap.h"

class Main 
{
private:
    void DoStuff();
    int step = 0;
    D3DGraphics gfx;
    FileSystem fs;
    MainMap * mainmap;
public:
    Main(HWND hWnd);
    void Go();
};
```

Main.cpp

```
    #include "Main.h"

Main::Main(HWND hWnd):
gfx(hWnd)
{
    mainmap = new MainMap(gfx, fs);
}

void Main::Go()
{
    gfx.BeginFrame();
    DoStuff();
    gfx.EndFrame();
}

void Main::DoStuff()
{
    mainmap->MainStage(gfx);
}
```

MainMap.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Main.h"

class MainMap
{
public:
    MainMap(D3DGraphics& gfx, FileSystem& fs);
    void MainStage(D3DGraphics& gfx);

private:
    void Render(D3DGraphics& gfx);
    int landtype[256][256] = {};
    int landtypenew[256][256] = {};
};
```

MainMap.cpp

```
#include "MainMap.h"

MainMap::MainMap(D3DGraphics & gfx, FileSystem & fs)
{
    for (int mapx = 0; mapx < 256; ++mapx)
    {
        for (int mapy = 0; mapy < 256; ++mapy)
        {
            landtype[mapx][mapy] = (int(rand() % 5) + 1);
            if (rand() % 100 < 75) landtype[mapx][mapy] = 5;
        }
    }
}

void MainMap::MainStage(D3DGraphics & gfx)
{
    //does stuff
    Render(gfx);
}

void MainMap::Render(D3DGraphics& gfx)
{
    //renders stuff
}
```

Now the issue doesn't *seem* to be with any of the coding. I can run the program perfectly fine and it works as I need it to. However, if I change any of the code in MainMap.cpp, it throws up three errors:

```
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note C++ does not support default-int
syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

all from line 13 in Main.h, which is

```
MainMap * mainmap;
```

However if I comment out this line along with the two lines in Main.cpp referring to mainmap, compile the program, then remove the comments and run it it works fine (and all the code is literally exactly the same)

It's becoming tiring having to do this every time I want to make a change to the MainMap.cpp file, can someone tell me if there is something wrong with what I'm doing and how it can be fixed? In case you need to know I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this on different IDE? If code is literally the same, then errors/warnings should be the same. If on different IDE there is no error like this, then it's IDE related problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile `MainMap.cpp`, it includes `MainMap.h` which in turn includes `Main.h`. When `Main.h` includes `MainMap.h` again, it is left out because of the `#pragma once` which tells the compiler to only include this file once per compilation unit. Therefore, in `Main.h`, the type `MainMap` is unknown.

Instead of including `MainMap.h` in `Main.h`, you can just forward declare the class since you are only using a pointer to it:

```
// in Main.h

#pragma once
#include "D3DGraphics.h"
#include "Filesystem.h"
//#include "MainMap.h"
class MainMap;
```

---

Edit:

Along with the change mentioned above, you also don't need to include `Main.h` in `MainMap.h`. `MainMap.h` has references to `D3DGraphics` and `FileSystem` but not `Main`, so just include those files:

```
// in MainMap.h

#pragma once
//#include "Main.h"
#include "D3DGraphics.h"
#include "Filesystem.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your header files, Main.h and MainMap.h, refer to each other. Both of them should start with an incomplete definition of the other's class, i.e., `class Main; class MainMap;`